# iOS iPad simulator not working properly

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, interface-orientation

I have a game where the settings are landscape only. When I run it on an iPhone simulator in Xcode, it runs in landscape mode like it should. When I run it on an iPad simulator, the iPad doesn't go to landscape mode when it opens the app.

Why is this and how can I fix it? I have looked for an answer but was unable to find one.

In addition to the landscape problem the frames per second on the iPad is extremely low, at about 18 whereas the iPhone 6 is about 30 and the 4s is 55, is there anyway to get the frame rate of the bigger devices up? I am running Xcode 6.4

Comment: Stick to one question per post. And update your question with relevant details about how you have specified landscape-only on the iPad. Did you try testing on a real iPad?

Comment: I have not tested it on a real iPad yet. For landscape I have the boxes checked for landscape and unchecked for portrait in the project settings

Comment: Are they checked specifically under the iPad settings section?

Comment: It was not. Fixed the problem, thanks!